# How to use Square brackets in lua_getfield

Tags: c, lua

I have a file called conf.lua and has the following code:

```
tbl ={
    block_ip = true;
}
```

I have a code C is the following:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "tbl");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "block_ip");
ip->ip_str = lua_toboolean(L, -1);
```

The code works perfectly. But I wanted to use as follows:

```
tbl ={
        [[block_ip]] = true;
    }
```

It is possible adding Square brackets? If so how can I add?

Comment: `[[...`]]` is a string in lua. You can't assign to a string. That last block of lua code isn't valid. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: So to use that way I would have to use lua_pushstring?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: just curious etan I saw a file earlier today on a website in which he made use of Square brackets

Comment: Used them **where**? They are perfectly valid instead of double or single quotes (though they have different behavior for escape characters). But you can't just use them anywhere you feel like it. (i.e. `print([[foo]])` is as valid as `print("foo")` but just like you can't use `"tbl" = {}` you can't do `[[tbl]] = {}`).

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was wrong, in the file that I've seen is used inside of tbl. edited the topic for better clarification.

Comment: Right, those are just quoting a string key. Though technically that would need to be `tbl = { [ [[block_ip]] ] = true; }` to be legal `lua` I believe. They don't change anything. Your C code can't tell the difference.

Comment: I found the code. So my error was occurring in reading, was missing a Square brackets is the way you did. Thank you very much for clarifying the doubt, solved.

Answer (score 0):

> tbl = {
>          [[block_ip]] = true;
>   }
>   It is possible adding Square brackets? If so how can I add?

Yes, but you want a single brackets with a string in the middle:

```
tbl = {
       ["block_ip"] = true;
}
```

Lua allows the use of double brackets as string quotes, so you *could* write the above like this:

```
tbl = {
       [[[block_ip]]] = true;
}
```

But that would be unnecessary unless the quoted text contains line breaks, which would just be bizarre:

```
tbl = {
       [[[block_

        ip]]] = true;
}
```